# Convert a string of bits to unicode character in java

Tags: java, unicode, byte, bit

I'm trying to convert a string of bits into Unicode characters in java. Problem is that I only get chines signs etc.

String bits = "01010011011011100110000101110010"

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: What is "01010011011011100110000101110010" supposed to be converted into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Values <= 32bits

Use `Integer.parseInt` to parse the binary string, then convert it to byte array (using `ByteBuffer`) and finally convert byte array to `String`:

```
String bits = "01010011011011100110000101110010"
new String(
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(
        Integer.parseInt(bits, 2)
    ).array(), 
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
);
```

#### Values > 32bits

For arbitrary large `bits` String you can use also `BigInteger`:

```
new String(
    new BigInteger(bits, 2).toByteArray(),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
);
```

### Result

```
Snar
```

Comment: what if the bits string was longer than 64 bit ? that wouldn't fit into Long

Comment: Well, OP showed us only one example, which fits in integer

Comment: OP showed example but didn't say explicitly "bits string cannot be longer than 64" , I don't think we can assume it :)

Comment: @niceman Yes, good point. I added example which covers that, which is even simpler :)

Comment: This will presumably misbehave if the first bit is `1` (that is, if the first character has code-point U+0100 or higher), since the byte-array will have to have an extra padding byte in order to make sure the sign bit is `0`.